# Python website login and xpath

Tags: python, http, xpath

I'm new at programming and I was trying to login into a website and gather an object. The authentication page comes up first, then it goes to the page, however, I'm not able to authenticate.

```
from lxml import html

import requests

session = requests.Session()

response = session.get('https://123.com/auth?name=ABC&pw=ABC')

page = requests.get('123.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

alert = tree.xpath('//*[@id="casealertsdataview"]/div')

print (alert)
```

Comment: Might be easier with Selenium if you need to interact with the page such as perform login and navigate through links : http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, try the below code, and see if it succeed without errors. 

Then you could start processing the payload.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
from pprint import pprint
import requests
from sys import exit

user = 'ABC'
pw = 'ABC'

r = requests.get('https://123.com/', auth=('user', 'pw'))
r = requests.get(URL)

if r.status_code != 200:
    exit(r.status_code)

exit(r.status_code)
```